# Why does a single moving charge create magnetic field even though in the absence of other charges

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics

My question is like this, As we know according to the theory of relativity the magnetic field created by the current carrying wire is nothing but an electric field, when we observe the frame in which the electrons are at rest. So that net electric field is created by the positive charges which starts to accumulate while In motion (According to T.O.R).

So, when a single charge moves then why it creates the magnetic field even though all other charges are not present to produce the electric field so that we can call that field a magnetic field in the frame where the charge is in the motion?

Comment: I think you are focusing on the wrong bit. Special Relativity is about the kinematics, not electromagnetism. Electromagnetism is governed by [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Maxwell's_equations_in_vacuum) which just happen to offer neat formulation under relativistic boosts. This is the 'why' - Maxwell's equations. Electron does not need other electrons or currents etc. You can have single charged particle which will couple to electromagnetic fields.

Comment: Note also that magnetic field is not merely a result of relativistic boosts. Instead magnetic and electric fields are components of a larger electromagnetic tensor. Electric field becomes partially magnetic as a result of boosts and the other way round too, but there are certain limitations, e.g. [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_electromagnetic_fields#Invariants)

Comment: But when we focus on the researchers and a bit information from the internet they clearly call it as it is the consequence of relativity. And we are taught the same in our colleges that it is nothing but the consequence of relativity and its proofs are also available on the internet you can check it out!

Comment: Check out the [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_electromagnetic_fields#Invariants) link. If you give me electric and magnetic fields at one point in space, I should be able to tell you whether there exists any reference frame where this field corresponds to purely electrostatic, purely magnetostatic or field due to electromagnetic wave. No amount of boosting will mask that. Moreover, these three possibilities are exclusive. Magnetostatic field will not look like electrostatic field irrespective of how you boost. This is often not covered in the introductory courses.