# Why moving positive ions would not create magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Special relativity is always used to explain the origin of magnetism (length contraction). It claims that magnetic field does not exist if we are moving along with electrons. (Electron is at rest from our perspective) However, the positive ions should be moving in opposite direction based on our perspective, therefore magnetic field exists because **moving** positive ions created it.

Comment: Special relativity cannot explain all cases of electromagnetism due to moving electric charges.

Comment: Looks a probable duplicate here you might find your answer   https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65335/how-do-moving-charges-produce-magnetic-fields and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687859/why-does-a-single-moving-charge-create-magnetic-field-even-though-in-the-absence and here as well

Comment: are you say the positive ions (atoms) are moving in opposite direction please give it a second thought! imagine there is a hole in the soil then I dug out another hole but filled the first hole with the debris taken from the 2nd hole, did the hole move? ;D

Answer (score 0):

Special relativity explains the magnetic field inside a current carrying conductor to be a result of a net electric field created by length contraction of the wire and positive ions but not electrons.

Due to their motion positive ions of the metal become length contracted which creates a positive charge density in the wire.